# Evaluating NServiceBus+MSMQ: Listening to two queues, is a message only processed once?

Tags: rabbitmq, nservicebus, msmq

We're evaluating NServiceBus, principally with MSMQ. We're keen to look towards scalability and reliability.

Theoretically speaking, if we were to have two compute units/Windows Services/etc., would the message be processed twice (potentially)?

We're trying to understand where the magic could happen, if it does. Is it in NServiceBus as the "application", or RabbitMQ as the "transport" over and above the basic MSMQ.

Or is this a daft question from someone who needs to know more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each "compute unit" (we call them **endpoints**, although it is possible to host multiple logical message processing endpoints within a single physical process boundary) would listen to only one queue. Any message added to a queue would only be processed by the endpoint listening to that queue.

That is, unless you're using Pub/Sub, in which case both endpoints could subscribe to the same event, but then each queue would get a copy of the message, and each endpoint (subscriber) would process it independently.

Or, it's possible using any of the centralized broker-based transports (Rabbit is one of them - basically anything except MSMQ) to have two **endpoint instances** working on the same server in a **competing consumers pattern**. In this case, as the name suggests, the processes will compete for messages.

In RabbitMQ, the first endpoint instance will Peek at the message, which will lock it out from other endpoint instances on the same queue, until the message is successfully received, or released for a retry. The SQL Transport and Azure transports work similarly.

NServiceBus isn't really an application. The metaphor of an Ethernet network applies pretty well:

- Message Transport (MSMQ/Rabbit/etc) <=> Ethernet network
- NServiceBus DLLs <=> Ethernet adapter
- Your message handling classes <=> Applications communicating over Ethernet

Comment: Thanks @David. With respect to your first paragraph, and apologies if I wasn't clear originally, if two endpoints are listening to the same queue (is this what you call Pub/Sub?) will this message be processed twice?

Comment: Talking generally, if you Receive the message then only the first endpoint to do so gets the message. If you Peek the message then every endpoint can read it until some process Receives the message.

Comment: @Program.X edited my answer related to competing consumers.

Comment: Thanks very much. We're investigating the opportunity to scale and need to look into unintended consequences of this so your guidance was most helpful.